# CSS gradient on a pseudo element in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, linear-gradients

Knows someone a solution for setting a CSS gradient on a pseudo element in IE9?

This is my approach:

http://jsbin.com/iquhut/edit#html,live

It seems like filter does not apply on pseudo elements or I missed something out?

Comment: I know what a pseudo-class is. I'm not sure what you mean by pseudo-element.

Comment: "The ':before' pseudo-element can be used to insert some content before the content of an element." via [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)

Comment: @Peter Olson: Pseudo-elements are imaginary elements that are created and rendered by browsers to either provide generated content or to surround certain parts of existing content. They're there purely for display and styling purposes - you won't find them in the DOM for example. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#pseudo-elements and http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The almost same effect is possible with a simple box-shadow by setting a negative spread-radius.

```
inset? && [ <offset-x> <offset-y> <blur-radius>? <spread-radius>? <color>? ]
```

[image: CSS Shadow]

Example: ( http://jsbin.com/ekehoz/edit#html,live )

```
box-shadow: 0px -15px 30px -10px #888;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use images.
IE9 does not support css gradients (-ms- prefix works for IE10 only), and dx filters (which you used in exapmle code) are very bad for performance (and buggy).

Alternatively, you can use canvas to render gradient, and then set that gradient as data-url background for your element.

Alternatively, you might use SVG gradient backgrounds, but then you will need to hide them from other browsers (good thing, we still have conditional comments in ie9). Keep in mind they are [buggy](http://my.opera.com/c69/blog/svg-repaint-bug-case-study) too. But not as buggy as filters.

Comment: Good answer, although there is no example to look at. I've been messing around trying to create the svg I want for hours. Ideally I could get a simple linear gradient rotated say 80deg, have it fill 100% width and height, and set it as a base64 svg+xml background image.
I realize this is a lot of work to ask you, but could you point me to some examples, or at least provide one for part of this solution.

Comment: @bodine if its still relevant to you (after almost a year), here is the link with example: my old [minesweeper game](http://vesna.in.ua/minesweeper), where tiles are generated via canvas.